# About removing a curve from Hirzebruch surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From Beauville's book on complex algebraic surface, in Chapter IV, we know each Hirzebruch surface contains a **unique** irreducible curve with negative self-intersection. If we **remove** this curve from the Hirzebruch surface, different from contraction, it will result in a non-compact surface. I'm wondering what we can say about this non-compact surface. For example, what kind of symmetry does it have, will it still be toric?

More generally, what if we remove an irreducible curve **different from** the one with negative self-intersection instead, how will it affect the situation above?

I'd appreciate any relevant discussions or comments, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hirzebruch surface is toric and its exceptional curve is invariant under the torus action (because it is unique), therefore its complement is also a toric variety.

Comment: I see! So if instead we take a curve other than this negative self-intersection one, we want to know if that is invariant under torus action. Do you have any clue which type of curves can they possibly be?

Comment: There are exactly four toric-invariant curves on the Hirzebruch surface --- the exceptional section, one non-exceptional section, and two fibers.

Comment: Thanks. Intuitively, this sounds true to me, I'm wondering if we can explicitly refer to them. For example, for the torus invariant non-exceptional curve, maybe its class shall be the one in $Pic (\mathbb{F}_n)$  of the tautological bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_n}(1)$? For the fiber ones, it seems harder to refer to them.

Comment: It is the class of a section that has zero intersection product with the exceptional section.

Comment: Yeah I agree! I think those are exactly the ones corresponding to the tautological bundle.